# Link a PHP file into HTML

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie so not very sure about this :)

So I have my project in HTML and a few stuff in a javascript separate file. All is linked and working.
However I have created a form in my HTML and would like to be able to use it for the user to get in touch with me and receive the message to my email address.

I have this code in a separate file called **contact.php** :

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="your@email.address";
    $subject="Form to email message";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

However, I do not know how to link this file into my HTML? is there anyone able to assist please?

Many thanks :))))

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PHP in .html files because the server does not recognize that as a valid PHP extension unless you tell it to. To do this you need to create a .htaccess file in your root web directory and add this line to it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

This will tell Apache to process files with a .htm or .html file extension as PHP files.